# psycopg2 on cygwin: no such process

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to install postgrepsql to cygwin on a windows 7 machine and want it to work with django.

After built and installed postgrepsql in cygwin, I built and installed psycopg2 in cygwin as well and got no error, but when use it in python with cygwin, I got the "no such process" error:

> > > import psycopg2
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >       File "", line 1, in 
> > >       File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 60, in 
> > >       from _psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
> > >       ImportError: No such process

any clues?

Thanks!

Jerry

Comment: Out of curiosity - why haven't you installed the native windows versions of Postgres,psycopg2?

Answer (score 1):

The `no such process` error comes about because psycopg2 is looking for cygpq.dll and can't find it.

When you install postgres from source, it puts this .dll in /usr/local/pgsql/lib/

Evidently, cygpq.dll is resolved by the win32 process loader, NOT cygwin or python, so you have to put it somewhere on your Windows path. A good spot is /usr/local/bin.

```
cp /usr/local/pgsql/lib/cygpq.dll /usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to reinstall libpq5.

Answer (score 0):

Why? There is native psycopg2 for Win.

Comment: And a native Postgres for Windows. I don't think the cygwin port actually includes a supported postgres version

Answer (score 0):

you could try these:
http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/